# I can't add the skin modifier anymore

Tags: armature

So I was following a tutorial on making a character in blender using the skin modifier and I forgot to duplicate my dude so I can later add the armature. Now, I want to add an armature using the skin modifier, but whenever I try to add the skin modifier, blender crashes. What do I do now?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Obviously only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe in detail what the issue is, supported by [accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Also This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)